# Jquery XML ie8 not working properly

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8

I'm using jquery 1.6.2. The error shown in my ie console is   Unexpected call to method or property access. jquery.min.js, line 17 character 29094.

I tested on all modern browser and it's working perfectly without any error on the console, but when trying on ie8, my xml file is not loading. My ajax call is OKAY, since selectXml get to run, but not the code inside (it shouldn't have any problem since it's working on other browser and I already did an XML validation), been struggling for hours. I think that ie8 is not working properly with jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "menu.xml",
    dataType:"text",
    success: selectXml
});
```

(my selectXml function)

```
function selectXml (xml) {

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    console.log(xmlDoc);
    var i = 0,
    j = 0,
    k = 0,
    l = 0,  
    maxCat = $(xmlDoc).find("categorie").length,
    maxPage = 14,
    numPlate = 0,
    numSection = 2,
    page = 0,
    queryXml,
    title,
    theNo, 
    thePlate,
    thePrice,  
    theSection;

    //for each page divide it in 2 sections
    for(i=1; i<=maxPage; i++){
        if( j < maxCat){
        //for each sections add the title and left, right section

            //for each left right section, fill up the dishes
            for(k=0; k<numSection; k++){

                queryXml = $(xmlDoc).find('categorie').eq(j);


                title = queryXml.find("title[lang=" + jQuery.fn.language + "]").text();
                numPlate = queryXml.find('plate').length;
                $('#menu'+ i).append('<section></section>');
                $('section').eq(j).append('<div class="menuTitle"><h1>'+ title +'</h1><div class="ribbon"></div></div><div class="menuLeft"><ul></ul></div><div class="menuRight"><ul></ul></div>');
                theSection = $('section').eq(j);

                for(l=0; l<numPlate; l++){
                    if(l< (numPlate/2)){
                        theNo = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('number').text();
                        thePrice = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('price').text();
                        thePlate = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('description[lang='+jQuery.fn.language+']').text();
                        //console.log(thePlate);
                        $('section').eq(j).find('.menuLeft ul').append('<li><span class="itemNumber">' + theNo +'</span><span class="itemName">'+ thePlate+'</span> <span class="itemPrice">'+ thePrice+'</span></li>');


                    }
                    else {
                        theNo = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('number').text();
                        thePrice = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('price').text();
                        thePlate = queryXml.find('plate').eq(l).find('description[lang='+jQuery.fn.language+']').text();
                        $('section').eq(j).find('.menuRight ul').append('<li><span class="itemNumber">' + theNo +'</span><span class="itemName">'+ thePlate+'</span> <span class="itemPrice">'+ thePrice+'</span></li>');
                    }


                };


                    numPlate = $(this).find('plate').length;

                j++;

            }

        }//end if
    }//end for



}
```

Comment: Can you replace the jQuery script file with the non-minified version? That would make debugging easier.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to make IE8 understand html5 elements first by including something like Modernizr (http://modernizr.com/) to your page. Then let the rest run as we expect.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is at the append code, where I use sections as container. ie8 probably don't understand it, which is why it doesn't show the info even tho when you do alert it shows the content of my xml correctly... what a mess. freaken IE... Here is my solution, replacing section to div with some class. 
Lesson: dont use html5 element for ie when using jquery changing the dom

Answer (score 0):

I using this code below and it work for me. I test on IE8, IE9, chrome, ff no problem at all!

```
// XML content look like this
<root>
    <publish>
        <store>
            <book title="How to fix IE"/>
            <book title="...."/>
        </store>
    </publish>
</root>


// Build XML document
var xDoc = $.parseXML(strXml);

// create new child element using XML Document
var xBook = xDoc.createElement("book");
xBook.setAttribute("title", "How to fix bad ass IE!");
// or you can using jquery
$(xBook).attr("authr", "Bill ...");

// Append child element to some where in XML Document
var xStore = $(xDoc).find("store");
xStore.append(xBook);
```